# jquery add class to element inside this element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is for a user account. When the user hits the edit button I want an edit box to be displayed inside the element where the button exists.

So I have this markup

```
<div class="col account">
    <strong>Account Settings</strong>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Profile Status</span>
                <p><?= $this->escape($this->status); ?></p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Name</span>
                <p> <?= $this->escape($this->name); ?></p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Username</span> 
                <p><?= $this->escape($this->username); ?></p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Bio</span>
                <p><?= $this->escape($this->bio); ?></p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Email</span>
                <p><?= $this->escape($this->email); ?></p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 5
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Password</span>
                <p>**********</p>
                <button class="edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="edit-box">
                    edit 6
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I have jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.edit-btn').click(function()
    {
        $('.edit-box').addClass('open');
    });
});
```

Is there a way to add a class only to the .edit-box that lives in the same .col as the .edit-btn?

Here is a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y6ukq3th/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `.siblings('.edit-box')` to add the class to the one who has that as a sibling of the clicked button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit-btn').click(function() {
         $(this).siblings('.edit-box').addClass('open');
     });
 });
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y6ukq3th/1/)

Comment: Ah thanks I knew it was something simple like that just couldnt find the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.edit-btn').click(function() {

        // clear all first ( if you want to do )
        // $('.edit-box').removeClass('open');

        // select in parent of target
        $(this).parents('.col:first').find('.edit-box').addClass('open');

        // [or] select between siblings of target
        // $(this).siblings('.edit-box').addClass('open');

        // [or] select next node of target
        // $(this).next().addClass('open');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mvrv7065/